# Is it a bad practise to use the useState and useReducer hook at the same time in React? My to-do list is not working as supposed to

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The application works fine in most cases, however, after either toggling or deleting a particular task, I am then unable to add tasks to the task list. I have no errors, it's more of a flaw in logic but I'm not too sure where the problem arises. Any help would be appreciated.

**This is my App component.**

```
import TodoForm from "./TodoForm";
import TodoList from "./TodoList";

const initialTodos = [];

function App() {
//array object that has to be mapped, default state is an empty array...
  const [taskDetails, setTaskDetails] = useState([]);
  
  const addTaskHandler = (enteredTask) => {
    // setTask(enteredTask);
    const updatedTasks = initialTodos.push({task: enteredTask, id: enteredTask.toString(), complete:false});
    setTaskDetails(updatedTasks); 
    console.log('Task added, updated tasks are:');
    console.log(taskDetails);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>To do list sample</h2>
    <TodoForm onAddTask={addTaskHandler}/>
    <TodoList tasks={taskDetails} initialTasks={initialTodos}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**This is my TodoForm component:**

```
import { useState } from "react";


const TodoForm = (props) => {

    const [ task, setTask] = useState('');

    const submitFormHandler  = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        props.onAddTask(task);
        setTask('');
    }

    const taskInputChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setTask(event.target.value);
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={submitFormHandler}>
                <label>Enter Task:
                    <input type='text' value={task} onChange={taskInputChangeHandler}/>
                </label>
                <button type="submit">ADD</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )

}

export default TodoForm;
```

**This is my todo-list component:**

```
const ACTIONS = {
    TOGGLE : "Toggle",
    DELETE : "Delete"
};

const reducer = ( tasks,action ) => {
    
    if (action.type === ACTIONS.TOGGLE){
        // console.log(action);
        return tasks.map((task) => { 
            // console.log(action.payload.id);           
            if (task.id === action.payload.id) {
              return { ...task, complete: !task.complete };
            } else {
              return task;
            }
          });
}

    if (action.type === ACTIONS.DELETE){
        
        console.log('Delete shit');
        
        //if the task id in NOT equal to the action id we keep it, otherwise get rid of it.
        tasks = tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== action.payload.id);
        console.log(tasks);
        return tasks;        
    }
}

const TodoList = (props) => {

    const initialTodos = props.initialTasks;    

    const [tasks, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialTodos);
    
    console.log('We are in todolist.js');
    //value of initial to-do's is updated after every new entry....
    //on deletion the state is updated but the initial to-dos stay the same....
    console.log(initialTodos);

    const handleToggle = (event) => {
        dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.TOGGLE, payload: {id: event.target.value} });
        console.log('toogle arg')
        // console.log(task.id)
      };
    
    const handleDelete = (event) => {
        dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.DELETE, payload: {id: event.target.value} });
      };
    
    return(
            <ul>
                {tasks.map( (task) => {
            return <li key={task.id}> 
                    <span style={ {color: task.complete ? 'red':'green'} }>
                    {task.task}
                    </span>  
                    <button onClick={handleToggle} value={task.task}>Toggle</button>
                    <button onClick={handleDelete} value={task.task}>Delete</button> 
                    </li> 
                })}

            </ul>
    );

}

export default TodoList;
```

Comment: `initialTodos.push(...)` is a mistake, don't mutate your state. Make a copy of your current array, add the task to that and then use that to set your state.

Comment: There is no problem in using useState and useReducer, but you are initializating a state (tasks) using a reducer value (initialTodos), I don't think that's a good idea. I would get rid of the state (tasks), and just use the useReducer in the parent (App).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in a previous comments, there is no problem in using both hooks.

However, using bith hook for updating different lists that represents the same thing (initialTodos & tasks) will probably end giving you some problems.

I would encourage you to just use useReducer to update the list, and move it to the parent component, like this:

```
import React, { useState, useReducer } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

const ACTIONS = {
  TOGGLE: "Toggle",
  DELETE: "Delete",
  ADD: "Add"
};

const initialTodos = [];

const reducer = (todos, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.TOGGLE:
      return todos.map((task) => {
        return task.id === action.payload.id
          ? { ...task, complete: !task.complete }
          : {};
      });
    case ACTIONS.DELETE: {
      return todos.filter((task) => task.id !== action.payload.id);
    }
    case ACTIONS.ADD: {
      return [...todos, action.payload];
    }
    default:
      return todos;
  }
};

export default function App() {
  const [todos, dispatchTodos] = useReducer(reducer, initialTodos);

  const addTaskHandler = (taskName) => {
    dispatchTodos({
      type: ACTIONS.ADD,
      payload: {
        task: taskName,
        id: taskName,
        complete: false
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>To do list sample</h2>
      <TodoForm onAddTask={addTaskHandler} />
      <TodoList todos={todos} dispatchTodos={dispatchTodos} />
    </div>
  );
}

const TodoForm = (props) => {
  const [task, setTask] = useState("");

  const submitFormHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.onAddTask(task);
    setTask("");
  };

  const taskInputChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setTask(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={submitFormHandler}>
        <label>
          Enter Task:
          <input type="text" value={task} onChange={taskInputChangeHandler} />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">ADD</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

const TodoList = (props) => {
  const { todos, dispatchTodos } = props;

  const handleToggle = (event) => {
    dispatchTodos({
      type: ACTIONS.TOGGLE,
      payload: { id: event.target.value }
    });
  };

  const handleDelete = (event) => {
    dispatchTodos({
      type: ACTIONS.DELETE,
      payload: { id: event.target.value }
    });
  };

  return (
    <ul>
      {todos.map((task) => {
        return (
          <li key={task.id}>
            <span style={{ color: task.complete ? "red" : "green" }}>
              {task.task}
            </span>
            <button onClick={handleToggle} value={task.task}>
              Toggle
            </button>
            <button onClick={handleDelete} value={task.task}>
              Delete
            </button>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Comment: Much appreciated =)